# DOMContentLoaded vs. 'load' event vs. "Finish"

Tags: seo, javascript, browsers, dom

I understand that the [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events), has already been answered, and as such it explains the last two values (1.40s, 4.66s) from Developer Tools, but if the 'load' event  "*can load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page*", then is supposed to announce? I mean, the page is **actually** fully loaded after everlasting 32.36 seconds, when "Finish" happens, and the 'load' event kinda loses its meaning.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many web pages that make requests using JS are *never really fully loaded*, because they can always request more assets seconds, minutes or even hours later, either to update the page (think like Gmail) or as a result of a user action.

A simplified way to think about the `load` timer is that it measures the amount of time between when the page started loading and when the browser finished loading in all of the assets that were requested by the HTML and CSS.

The `Finish` timer, in contrast, measures the amount of time between when the page started loading and when the browser *finished making its last request*.

It's a little more complicated than that but that's the general gist.

For a web page that makes no requests after the page finishes loading, the `Finish` timer should stop shortly after the `load` timer. But for a web page that makes AJAX requests, the `Finish` timer will continue to run as the page continues to make requests after page load.

Comment: `the Finish timer should stop shortly after the load timer.` how come its not identical?